# internal Server Error CrazyDomains

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I would like to ask if there's something wrong to my webhost or with my code.

I successfully try and test all over my custom php website on my localserver using wamp.

As I upload into my webhost (i used crazydomains) and setup the database usernames, passwords etc.

And when the time I accessed it, it says internal server error.

Have you encounter this already?

Comment: It's your code. Check the server log for error messages and post them - and the relevant code - here.

Comment: @jeroen It could also be that hes using a webserver module in his .htaccess or on his local vhost that is not available on the deployment server... for example they may not have `mod_rewrite` loaded for some godforsaken reason. @OliverJake check your error logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: @prodigitalson True, but if you use things that the server does not support (could also be mismatching php versions / unavailable features for example...), the problem is still the code in my opinion. Anyway, without error messages and the code involved, there is not much anybody can do.

Comment: I am suspecting that its password_hash() function that i used.
But as I check the php documentation the server is qualified on its php version which is 5.4.. How can I do a custom error logs?
I checked on the browser's console it says:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you are using `password_hash()` and the php version on the server is 5.4. That is going to lead to fatal errors for an undefined function as `password_hash()` is available from php 5.5 on.

There is a library to provide forward compatibility for these functions, [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

This will solve your problems where `password_hash()` is concerned, but if you run into more problems, you should add error handling and display them to see what is going on. To do that, just add this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! :D
And also fixed some line of codes that has [ require_once '/folder/file.php' into require_once './folder/file.php' ]...
Thank you so much once again. ^_^